# String replace with multiple dahses and spaces

Tags: javascript

I have a number of strings which are formated like this one:

> Vincent van Gogh - The Garden of Saint Paul's Hospital (Leaf-Fall) -
>   12345

And I'm trying to change the string with javascript to this:

> Vincent-van-Gogh-The-Garden-of-Saint-Pauls-Hospital-Leaf-Fall-12345

I'm essentialy wanting to strip out `,'()` from the titles, change the " - " and blank spaces to "-".

I can strip the punctuation like this:

```
str.replace(/[,'()]/g,"");
```

So I tried this to try and get rid of that space dash space:

```
replace(/[ - ]/g,"");
```

But then I end up with this:

> VincentvanGogh-TheGardenofSaintPaul'sHospital(Leaf-Fall)-12345

Comment: Can you post your expected value please?

Comment: the second code block is the expected value

Comment: `str.match(/\w+/g).join("-");` - note that this also strips other non-word-characters, e.g. "[" or "]", but reading your question, i feel like that is actually desired behavior.

Comment: `str.replace(/[,'()\s+]/g,'-').replace(/-+/g,'-');` <-- This should help as well :) Something similar to @thefourthbird's approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your are using a character class `[ - ]` to a range from a whitespace to a whitespace. You could remove one of the whitespaces and repeat that one or more times `[ -]+` and replace that with a dash:

```js
let str = "Vincent van Gogh - The Garden of Saint Paul's Hospital (Leaf-Fall) - 12345";
console.log(str.replace(/[,'()]/g,"").replace(/[ -]+/g, '-'));
```

Comment: @ASDFGerte Of course, thank you! I have updated my answer